# How to run a task on stop event in debugging?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I tried the `postDebugTask` but it doesn't seem to run the task at all. I've skimmed [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) as well to no avail.

./.vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Node.js in Docker",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "run",
            "platform": "node",
            "removeContainerAfterDebug": true,
            "postDebugTask": "stop"
        }
    ]
}
```

./.vscode/tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "run",
            "command": "docker-compose up serve ; docker-compose rm -fsv serve",
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "stop",
            "command": "echo test | docker-compose rm -fsv serve",
        },
    ]
}
```

How can I make it so that `docker-compose rm -fsv serve` runs in parallel if the stop event occurs in the debug?